# What's the minimum kinetic energy required to overcome static friction?

Tags: energy, friction

Suppose I have a still (granite) cube on a flat surface with friction with gravity evenly pulling down on everything. I know how to calculate how much force something such as electromagnetism would require to move the cube and overcome static friction but how fast would I have to throw a (granite) ball at the cube to make it overcome static friction? How much momentum and how much kinetic energy would the ball require?

Comment: Am I understanding properly in that you don't just want to act a force on the stationary cube, but you want to throw something at it to impart an impulse on the cube?

Comment: @SamBlitz Yes you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your objects were both 100% perfectly rigid and perfectly hard, then any nonzero amount of kinetic energy which is enough to have the ball hit the cube (without being stopped by its own friction before it hit) would be enough.

Though of course such a small kinetic energy would not make the cube move much, so kinetic friction would stop the cube before it moved very far.

Comment: Imagine a ball in a valley. You can push the ball up the sides of the valley but unless you fully lift it out of the valley it will just fall back down into the bottom. Unless I'm mistaken shouldn't the cube and the floor have a similar situation where one can slightly disturb the cube from its position but unless enough energy is given it will simply fall back into its previous place?

Comment: @StevenStewart-Gallus Not with the model of a rigid cube on a rigid table with a coefficient of static friction. A real table will form an actual little valley as the cube pressed down on it. A deeper valley for a heavier cube. But that's different than static friction, and it wouldn't happen if the table is perfectly rigid.

Comment: @Timeaus Aren't cubes and tables bumpy and filled with valleys and hills at an atomic level though?

Comment: @StevenStewart-Gallus Real materials aren't rigid either. But if you want a nonzero energy barrier you'll have to specify the stiffness and as you get stiffer the energy needed goes down. But as I said, if there is kinetic friction then it won't go far when it's a small energy.

Answer (score 1):

The effect the ball has on the cube does not only depend on its momentum or kinetic energy. What might or might not move the cube is the force exerted by the ball. When the ball hits the cube, it takes some time to be stopped, depending on the deformation caused. The shorter the time the higher the force and the more likely it is large enough to overcome static friction.
In short, one needs the momentum of the ball and the time it takes until the ball is stopped.

Comment: Are you saying a soft (maybe rubber) cube would be harder to move than a hard (such as granite) cube? That seems reasonable to me. In that case, I want to know the answer for the simpler case of the hard (granite) cube.

Comment: It also depends on the projectile, I hope you know. Again, if you had a rubber ball, it would require more energy to push it than if you had a granite ball.